# How to set up a new value in pandas but keep the original data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
   admit   gpa  gre  rank
   0  3.61  380     3
   1  3.67  660     3
   1  4.00  800     1 
   1  3.19  640     4
   0  2.93  520     4
```

I want to set up a new pandas data frame for the first row but keep the original data frame like:

```
   admit   gpa  gre  rank
   0  3.61  380     5

   admit   gpa  gre  rank
   0  3.61  380     3
   1  3.67  660     3
   1  4.00  800     1 
   1  3.19  640     4
   0  2.93  520     4
```

I have tried:

df_value = pd.DataFrame(df[0:(0 + 1)])
df_value.set_value(0, 'rank', 5)

However, when I change a value in new pandas, the value in the original is also changed.
Do you have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use copy() function:

```
>>> df_value = df[:1].copy()
>>> df_value["rank"] = 5
>>> df
   admit   gpa  gre  rank
0      0  3.61  380     3
1      1  3.67  660     3
2      1  4.00  800     1
3      1  3.19  640     4
4      0  2.93  520     4
>>> df_value
   admit   gpa  gre  rank
0      0  3.61  380     5
```